# Yandex Traffic layer position issue with using openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, traffic, yandex-maps

I have an issue with traffic map with using openlayers library.

The traffic layer is shifting from the sublayer, so roads and streets are mismatched.

The code from jsfiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/L4qubkhd/.

[image: Example image]

```
var projection1 = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326');
var displayProjection1 = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913');
var centerLat = 55.75;
var centerLon = 37.62;  

function yandex_getTileURL(bounds) {
    var r = this.map.getResolution();
    var maxExt = (this.maxExtent) ? this.maxExtent : YaBounds;
    var w = (this.tileSize) ? this.tileSize.w : 256;
    var h = (this.tileSize) ? this.tileSize.h : 256;
    var x = Math.round((bounds.left - maxExt.left)/(r * w));
    var y = Math.round((maxExt.top - bounds.top)/(r * h));
    var z = this.map.getZoom();
    var lim = Math.pow(2, z);
    if (y <0>= lim) {
        return OpenLayers.Util.getImagesLocation() + "404.png";
    } else {
        x = ((x % lim) + lim) % lim;

        var url = (this.url) ? this.url : "http://vec02.maps.yandex.net/";
        //console.log("http://vec0"+((x+y)%5)+".maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=map&v=2.16.0&x=" +x + "&y=" + y + "&z=" + z + "");
        return "http://vec02.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=map&v=2.16.0&x=" +x + "&y=" + y + "&z=" + z + "";

       // return url + "tiles?l=map&v=2.2.3&x=" + x + "&y=" + y + "&z=" + z;
    }
};
function yandex_traffic_getTileURL(bounds) {
    var r = this.map.getResolution();
    var maxExt = (this.maxExtent) ? this.maxExtent : YaBounds;
    var w = (this.tileSize) ? this.tileSize.w : 256;
    var h = (this.tileSize) ? this.tileSize.h : 256;
    var x = Math.round((bounds.left - maxExt.left)/(r * w));
    var y = Math.round((maxExt.top - bounds.top)/(r * h));
    var z = this.map.getZoom();
    var lim = Math.pow(2, z);
    if (y <0>= lim) {
        return OpenLayers.Util.getImagesLocation() + "404.png";
    } else {
        x = ((x % lim) + lim) % lim;
        var url = (this.url) ? this.url : "http://jgo.maps.yandex.net/1.1/"; 
    return  url + "tiles?l=trf,trfe,trfl&lang=tr_TR&z=" + z + "&x=" + x + "&y=" + y + "&tm=1445001388";
    }
};

var options = {
        projection : new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        displayProjection : new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), 
        maxExtent : new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34), 
         maxResolution: 'auto',
        numZoomLevels : 19,
        isBaseLayer:true,
        units : "m",
        transitionEffect : null,
        zoomMethod : null,
        controls : [new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(), new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults(), new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(), new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({
                zoomWheelEnabled : true,
                dragPanOptions : {
                    enableKinetic : true
                }
            }),new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({ascending:true})]
    };

var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',options);

var layerTraffic = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS("TrafficLayer", "http://jgo.maps.yandex.net/1.1/", {
        tileOrigin: new OpenLayers.LonLat(map.maxExtent.left, map.maxExtent.bottom),
        visibility : true,
        type : "png",
        getURL : yandex_traffic_getTileURL,
        isBaseLayer : false,
        transitionEffect : null,
        zoomMethod : null
    });

 var YaBounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34);



 var yandexMapLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Yandex("Yandex Map", { 
      sphericalMercator:true,
        type: "png",
        getURL: yandex_getTileURL,
        numZoomLevels: 18,
        attribution: '<a href="http://beta-maps.yandex.ru/">Яндекс.Карты</a>',
        transitionEffect: 'resize'
    });

var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google('Google Streets', // the default
    {
        numZoomLevels : 18

    });

map.addLayers([yandexMapLayer,gmap,layerTraffic]); 

 var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(centerLon,centerLat);
 lonlat.transform(map.displayProjection,map.projection);     
// map.setCenter(lonlat, 13); 
// 17501610 24592741    29.16935000 40.98790166 -0.19044156
 var yeditepeCad = new   OpenLayers.LonLat(17501610/600000.0,(24592741/600000.0)-0.19044156).transform( 
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));
map.setCenter(lonlat, 9);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is prohibited to use Yandex Maps tiles (including traffic ones) with third-party APIs (OpenLayers, for instance). You may easily do vice versa — show OpenStreetMap tiles using Yandex Maps API:
https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Layer-docpage/
see Example section.

Comment: I had to use OpenLayers . I can not change the system completely.